# Multiple select in administrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-administrate

Since administrate does not yet have support for multiple selects. Has anyone created a custom multiple select? Preferably one that works like the `HasMany` select.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here it is in case someone else needs it:

app/fields/multiple_select_field.rb

```
# app/fields/multiple_select_field.rb

require "administrate/field/base"

class MultipleSelectField < Administrate::Field::Select

  def to_s
    data
  end

  def self.permitted_attribute(attribute)
    { attribute.to_sym => [] }
  end

  def permitted_attribute
    self.class.permitted_attribute(attribute)
  end

end
```

app/views/fields/multiple_select_field/_form.html.erb

```
# app/views/fields/multiple_select_field/_form.html.erb

<div class="field-unit__label">
  <%= f.label field.attribute %>
</div>
<div class="field-unit__field">
  <%= f.select(
    field.attribute,
    options_from_collection_for_select(
      field.selectable_options,
      :to_s,
      :to_s,
      field.data.presence,
    ),
    {}, multiple: true,
  ) %>
</div>
```

app/views/fields/multiple_select_field/_index.html.erb

```
# app/views/fields/multiple_select_field/_index.html.erb
<%= field.to_param.join(', ') %>
```

app/views/fields/multiple_select_field/_show.html.erb

```
# app/views/fields/multiple_select_field/_show.html.erb
<%= field.to_param.join(', ') %>
```

Comment: Good stuff! How exactly do I incorporate this in attribute_dashboard.rb?

Comment: @Esseme Haven't worked with this in years but assuming you just have to use it in your view like you would with any other administrate field.

Comment: hi @dan-klasson, I am trying to implement bulk delete by providing checkbox to select records and delete multiple at once, can you please point me in the right direction as to how i can achieve this, thanks.

Comment: with probably the latest version of administrate gem, you would need to update `def self.permitted_attribute(attribute)` to `def self.permitted_attribute(attribute, _options = nil)`